Firebase Legacy to HTTP v1 Send request Payload changes
This doc -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1 -- gives a small example about how to change the payload, but it doesn't really apply to what I have.  Here is a small example of a current legacy payload:
{
  "to": "%SomeObj.SomeProp%",
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "notificationId": "%Message.Template%",
    "message": "Some message.",
  }
}

In the new HTTP v1 version, I don't see an example of how to replace "to:".  The example for the new one does:
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",
    blah blah blah

Their old example had "to": "/topics/news", and the new one is
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",

So my 2 questions are:

How do I replace "to":  What is it changed to?
I thought I read something about not using reserved words.  My old payload had "message": "Some message.", and we use that "message" property all through our client code.  Will I have to change all that code as well?


So these are data messages.  The "to": in our scheme refers to an Android device.  I'm looking around for the new syntax for sending to an Android device -- haven't found it yet.

Getting closer.  I can get a message with proper syntax.  But my OnMessageReceived is not being called.  I suspect it is the "to:" field.  I have it in the data section, but that must not be right.  The old syntax had it above the data stuff, but the new syntax doesn't allow that.   Is "to:" even allowed anymore?  Can't find the docs to tell me.

"to" has been replaced by "token".  Using "message" in the data section is fine.
